# What is $\Omega$ in the context of Poisson's equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, poissons-equation

I have recently started a new course on PDE's and have already stumbled on an example that I'm struggling to understand:

[image: Poisson]

The main aspect of this example that I am struggling to wrap my head around is not in the proof, it's in the way that $\Omega$ is used in the second and third lines.

Does $\Omega$ denote the solution space? i.e. Does $\Omega = (x,y,z)$ and $\partial \Omega = (\partial x , \partial y , \partial z)$ (if the problem is to be solved in 3 dimensions)?

Furthermore, if it is the case that $\Omega$ denotes the solution space for the problem, why is $\partial \Omega$ the boundary of the solution space?

Comment: I believe $\Omega$ is simply the domain over which you want to solve your PDE: a given region of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\partial \Omega$ is the domain's boundary, on which you are given the condition $u = 0$. The functional space in which to look for the solutions is another matter.

Comment: @Charles, I am not so sure that is relevant to the present question.

Comment: In a good course/book/whatever, it should be mentioned somewhere before the example, what $\Omega$ is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDEs, it is very common to denote the domain of the PDE with $\Omega$.

Common examples are a circle/ball 
$$
 \Omega = B_1(0) := \{ x\in \mathbb R^n : \|x\| < 1 \}
$$

or a square
$$
 \Omega = (0,1)\times (0,1)
$$

In this case $\partial\Omega$ denotes the boundary of the domain, and not partial derivatives!
For example, in the case of $\Omega=B_1(0)$
we have
$$
 \partial\Omega = \partial B_1(0) := \{ x\in \mathbb R^n : \|x\| = 1 \}
$$